# How can one use an apikey with Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 in C#?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, speech, api-key, google-cloud-speech

How can one use an apikey with Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 in C#?

I have **Google.Cloud.Speech.V1** version v1.0.1, VisualStudio 2017 and env var **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** auth is working fine. But I want to use ApiKeys and manage users by myself on backend. I already googled many days and did not find the solution.

## Code from Google tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

```
   var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
   var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();

   // Write the initial request with the config.
   await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
       new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
       {
           StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
           {
                Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                    SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                    LanguageCode = "en",
                },
                InterimResults = true,
            }
        });
    ...
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the Cloud Speech API doesn't permit the use of just API keys. (For most purposes, they're somewhat deprecated these days.)

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by creating jwt access token generator service which is emitting time-expiring tokens which is perfect for me.